# Since TrueCrypt isn't fully supported on Windows 7, what should I use?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption

<strike>I was running Windows Vista with TrueCrypt 6.2a encrypting the system partition. Upon Windows 7 upgrade, I discovered that TrueCrypt doesn't fully support Windows 7, so I had to remove the partition encryption (I still use TrueCrypt for in-Windows use).</strike>

I have checked, and apparently the next version will be able to do it (see http://www.truecrypt.org/future). Nevertheless, paranoid freak that I am, I want to encrypt my system partition again, and Bitlocker is out of the question.

So, despite all the obvious signs that TrueCrypt does NOT support Windows 7, has anyone actually tried it? If it really isn't supported, what should I use?

TrueCrypt 6.3 now supports Windows 7. I installed it last night and it works beautifully. Thanks for all your suggestions and comments.

Comment: Update: Note the answer below - TrueCrypt 6.3 has been released and officially supports Windows 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been using whole disk encryption with Truecrypt 6.2 since Windows 7 when RTM back in August. I've haven't had any issues with it.  You want an officially supported version of Truecrypt then they just released 6.3 on 10/21 which fully supports Windows 7.
http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=version-history

Answer (score 3):

Truecrypt 6.3 [fully supports](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=version-history) Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Why is Bitlocker out of the question?  I would just wait for it to be compatible or go back to a compatible OS.

Comment: Bitlocker requires TPM, or failing that, an external USB stick. I don't have TPM and I don't want to rely on USB.

My current plan is to wait for it to become compatible.

Comment: Sounds good although we have found it to be very reliable and just back up the key in case the thumb drive dies.

Answer (score 0):

There's [FreeOTFE](http://www.freeotfe.org/), which:

1. Claims to be compatible with Windows 7.
2. Is Free Software
3. Can also mount LUKS volumes created on Linux.

Comment: Nothing doing. Unsigned drivers. Sorry.

Comment: There's also the issue that I want to trust people involved with my security software.  There's various reasons I'd trust people, but not just because they write Free Software.  In addition, I wouldn't trust it to handle all my files just on a claim that it's compatible with Windows 7.  This isn't something like a compiler where I can use it, decide I don't like it, and delete it.  If this is faulty, I lose everything since the last backup, and have a good deal of work to do anyway.